# Android InstantiationException With Fragment (It Is Public)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a `Fragment` (it is not an inner class, and it does not have any constructor whatsoever)

```
public class PreferenceListFragment extends ListFragment implements OnClickListener
```

I'm getting this crash report on the Android Developer Console:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.redacted.redacted/com.redacted.redacted.PreferenceActivity}: 
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
Unable to instantiate fragment com.redacted.redacted.PreferenceListFragment$3:
make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is
public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1750)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1766)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2960)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:945)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3818)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
Unable to instantiate fragment com.redacted.redacted.PreferenceListFragment$3: 
make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that
is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1760)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:200)
at com.redacted.redacted.PreferenceActivity.onCreate(PreferenceActivity.java:37)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1710)
... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: 
com.redacted.redacted.PreferenceListFragment$3
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
... 18 more
```

I am unable to replicate this on any of my test devices.

Here's the `PreferenceActivity.onCreate` where the exception is occurring:

```
public class PreferenceActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    PreferenceListFragment frag;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.preference);

        frag = (PreferenceListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.preference_list_frag);
        frag.setState(AlarmPreferenceState.Selected);
        frag.setIsTwoPane(false);
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

And here is `R.layout.preference`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.redacted.redacted.PreferenceListFragment"
          android:id="@+id/preference_list_frag"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Anyone know why I might be getting this exception, and/or how to reproduce it?

Comment: I didn't fully understand this from the question: does your `PreferenceListFragment` class have any other constructors besides a no arguments one?

Comment: It has no constructor....a while back I was having another problem with a `Fragment` and someone on SO said not to have any constructor in a `Fragment`

Comment: Is the `PreferenceListFragment` class an inner class in some other class? If yes then make it `static`, otherwise you'll get that exception.

Comment: @Luksprog updated the question to reflect that it is not an inner class. I am also unable to reproduce this (I got the exception from the developer console)

Comment: When you say it has no constructor, do you mean not even an empty one? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor).

Comment: Judging by the stacktrace you're using anonymous fragment classes of `PreferenceListFragment` and Android can't instantiate them. If this is true than you should avoid those anonymous classes.

Comment: @Geobits there are no constructors whatsoever

Comment: @Luksprog As far as I know, I'm inflating them from XML. It works on every device I've tried it on. The only reason I know about it is because it showed up as reported on the developer console. I just wanna make sure it's not some bug that rarely pops up. Even worse than that would be if it were non-deterministic.

Comment: Could you share your project file structure or Manifest file ?

Comment: @VenoM the project file structure is the standard Eclipse structure for an Android project. What part of the Manifest would you like to see?

Comment: ohk! just the package declaration and if you could share the stuff you have written in `PreferenceListFragment`. Except for that  I couldn't find anything wrong in your project.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You `MUST` have an empty public constructor. Whoever told you to not have a fragment constructor steered you in the wrong direction.

What they might have told you, is to not have a constructor that accepts arguments, since those may not be called by the system when re-creating the fragments. In that case, use the example in the docs to supply arguments to your fragment.

Quoted from the docs :

> All subclasses of Fragment must include a public empty constructor. The framework will often re-instantiate a fragment class when needed, in particular during state restore, and needs to be able to find this constructor to instantiate it. If the empty constructor is not available, a runtime exception will occur in some cases during state restore. [1], [2]

[1] : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

[2] : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()

Comment: I'll try adding one and see if any more errors pop up. Thanks!

Comment: The default constructor is always present, unless we make it private.

Answer (score 3):

**CHECK YOUR PROGUARD RULES**

The strange thing in my case was, this error popped only in the release build and not in the debug build.

The issue was, I was using a `FragmentContainerView` to hold the `Fragment` and mentioned the `Fragment` class name in the XML itself, like this

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/f_navigation_fragment"
                class="com.example.MyFragmentClass"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This worked fine in the Debug build *(without Proguard Obfuscation)* but in the Release build *(with Proguard Obfuscation)* the actual `Fragment` class was Obfuscated and hence the XML was unable to locate it leading to OP's error.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378810/proguard-causing-runtime-exception-with-android-navigation-component/50378828#50378828) link for additional references.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I accidentally tried to navigate to an `abstract` Fragment class.