# Android Architecture Navigation component and Proguard results in java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-fragments, proguard, android-proguard, android-jetpack

When running a proguard enabled build with the new android navigation component, my fragment class cannot be found. I receive this stack trace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myapppackage.path, PID: 24334
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapppackage.path/com.myapppackage.path.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception inflating com.myapppackage.path:navigation/nav_graph line 7
    at androidx.navigation.h.a(Unknown Source:124)
    at androidx.navigation.c.a(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.a(Unknown Source:88)
    at android.support.v4.app.g.k(Unknown Source:15)
    at android.support.v4.app.m.a(Unknown Source:382)
    at android.support.v4.app.m.b(Unknown Source:7)
    at android.support.v4.app.m.a(Unknown Source:74)
    at android.support.v4.app.m.onCreateView(Unknown Source:216)
    at android.support.v4.app.j.a(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.support.v4.app.h.a(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.support.v4.app.e.onCreateView(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.support.v4.app.h.onCreateView(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.j.b(Unknown Source:23)
    at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.myapppackage.path.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapppackage.path.ui.start.StartFragment
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.a$a.a(Unknown Source:58)
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.a$a.a(Unknown Source:19)
    at androidx.navigation.h.a(Unknown Source:16)
    at androidx.navigation.h.a(Unknown Source:133)
    at androidx.navigation.h.a(Unknown Source:31)
    at androidx.navigation.c.a(Unknown Source:4) 
    at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.a(Unknown Source:88) 
    at android.support.v4.app.g.k(Unknown Source:15) 
    at android.support.v4.app.m.a(Unknown Source:382) 
    at android.support.v4.app.m.b(Unknown Source:7) 
    at android.support.v4.app.m.a(Unknown Source:74) 
    at android.support.v4.app.m.onCreateView(Unknown Source:216) 
    at android.support.v4.app.j.a(Unknown Source:4) 
    at android.support.v4.app.h.a(Unknown Source:2) 
    at android.support.v4.app.e.onCreateView(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.support.v4.app.h.onCreateView(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.j.b(Unknown Source:23) 
    at android.support.v7.app.c.setContentView(Unknown Source:4) 
    at com.myapppackage.path.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source:6) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6999) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6990) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapppackage.path.ui.start.StartFragment
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.navigation.fragment.a$a.a(Unknown Source:45)
            ... 38 more
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.myapppackage.path.ui.start.StartFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.myapppackage.path-yqk9eOoCoeyT3xg78oYcxg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.myapppackage.path-yqk9eOoCoeyT3xg78oYcxg==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            ... 41 more
```

It says it cannot find the fragment class which is defined in my `nav_graph.xml` file:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myapppackage.path.ui.start.StartFragment
```

My `nav_graph.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/start">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:name="com.myapppackage.path.ui.start.StartFragment"
        android:label="start_fragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/start_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

As you can see the name of the fragment is set in the xml, this path seems to become invalid after running through proguard.

My only work-around so far is to define each of my fragment class paths as `-keepnames` in my `proguard-rules.pro` file. For example:

```
-keepnames class com.myapppackage.path.ui.start.StartFragment
```

After this, the obfuscated compile runs fine without crashing.

Although I'm not sure if this is correct, am I doing something wrong?
How can we use the new navigation architecture component with our obfuscated builds without defining a rule for each fragment in proguard rules?

I understand this issue may only be a problem right now because the navigation-fragment component is still in alpha.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378828/2914696) has the solution for your problem.