# ClassNotFoundException when using androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to transition from using a `FrameLayout` to using `FragmentContainerView` and from the tutorials I've seen, it should be pretty easy. However, when I run my app after making the change, I get

```
Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
```

my layout file is pretty simple:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Do I need to add something into my build.gradle or something? Why can't it find the class?

Comment: If it is happening only in release builds, then it is a pro-guard issue. Check this quick fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61365688/3484700

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's in `androidx.fragment` 1.2.0 or higher:

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0"
```

Comment: Thanks! I figured I needed a statement like that, just couldn't find any documentation on how to format it

Comment: Same. It's a shame I had to google to find this.

Comment: For kotlin                                                                                                                 implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0'

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to [@Salam El-Banna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3484700/salam-el-banna) and his [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61365688/3484700), I found that in case an application crashes in `release` build we should add in `proguard-rules.pro` (one or two lines, depending on `android:name` in `<FragmentContainerView>`:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
# JetPack Navigation
# This fixes: 
# Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment: make sure class name exists
# Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists
#-------------------------------------------------

-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure their are no custom constructors like this. 
ex:

```
FragmentName (val ctx: Context): Fragment() {
```

change to

```
FragmentName: Fragment() {
```

The reason is when the inflater inflates FrgmentContainer, it calls default constructor to initialize the fragments. If their is no default constructor available, it will crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using kotlin the latest `FragmentContainerView` implementation stays under:

```
implementation("androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6")
```