# Replace the <fragment> tag with FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, android-fragments

Android Studio offers to replace a `<fragment>` tag in `Google Maps` fragment. In an application I don't have `Navigation`, but probably will add. Should I replace the `<fragment>` tag with `<FragmentContainerView>`?

[image]

Looking at https://proandroiddev.com/android-fragments-fragmentcontainerview-292f393f9ccf I found that we can also replace `<FrameLayout>` with `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`. Should we do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<FragmentContainerView... is meant to replace both <FrameLayout... and <Fragment...
Refer to this answer on a similar question.

[Answer on the benefit of using <FragmentContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59948595/11208036)

Comment: Thanks! Looking at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView I understood, that we should replace `<FrameLayout>` in an activity, not in fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [SABANTO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170938/2914140) I replaced `<fragment>` and `<FrameLayout>` with `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>` (replaced `<FrameLayout>` only in activities). It works right in `debug` build, but not in `release` where it crashes.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.example:layout/fragment_show_map: Binary XML file line #16 in com.example:layout/fragment_show_map: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16 in com.example:layout/fragment_show_map: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Looking at [ClassNotFoundException when using androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009473/classnotfoundexception-when-using-androidx-fragment-app-fragmentcontainerview) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/61365688/2914140 I found that we should add in `proguard-rules.pro` one or two lines, depending on what you have in XML file:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    ...
```

proguard-rules.pro:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
# JetPack Navigation
# This fixes: 
# Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment: make sure class name exists
# Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists
#-------------------------------------------------
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
-keepnames class com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

Don't forget to test your applications in `release` build (and in `debug` build, of course).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I used the androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Kotlin Code

```
    private val navController by lazy {
        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main) as NavHostFragment
        navHostFragment.navController
    }

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    }
```

when you just switch without changing the code since the default sample code by google android studio uses  it will give you an error you have to add to as well define the variable navController but I don't really understand why they recommend it if it was that different I find the  uses less code and works just fine