# Replace the <fragment> tag with FragmentContainerView, for adding Google Maps?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been following youtube tutorials to add google map to my android apps; Specifically this video [Google Maps API Setup (part2)](https://youtu.be/M0bYvXlhgSI?t=421) and this video [Step by Step Google Maps Implementation in Android App](https://youtu.be/pOKPQ8rYe6g?t=357).

In both videos above, they simply paste the copied Fragment code from the Documentation and paste it within the default constraint layout. But they don't get the same errors that I do.

Android studio keeps asking me to replace the fragment tag with fragmentContainerViewer.

I tried following both tutorials and looking through other similar questions here such as [Replace the  tag with FragmentContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64170603/replace-the-fragment-tag-with-fragmentcontainerview) But i don't understand what the solution is.

Here's the error messages: `Replace the <fragment> tag with FragmentContainerView.`

Here's my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SelectLocationMapActivity">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's my dependencies & plugins:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Any help at all is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: <FragmentContainerView... is meant to replace both <FrameLayout... and <Fragment... Refer to this answer on a similar question.


Answer on the benefit of using <FragmentContainerView :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58737769/androidx-fragment-app-fragmentcontainerview-vs-fragment-as-a-view-for-a-navh/59948595#59948595