# Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I updated navigation component to 2.3.2 version.

In the 2.3.1 version work normally

I was going through the documentation and I did not find anything about the error or about any update in the component

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.m.marketplace, PID: 16698
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.m.marketplace/com.m.marketplace.ui.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.m.marketplace:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.m.marketplace:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3311)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.m.marketplace:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #11 in com.m.marketplace:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11 in com.m.marketplace:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.downEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:263)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:314)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:334)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:118)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.updateState(NavBackStackEntry.java:150)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.setMaxLifecycle(NavBackStackEntry.java:130)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.popBackStackInternal(NavController.java:325)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:1050)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.navigate(NavController.java:942)
        at com.m.marketplace.utils.ktx.NavControllerKt.navigateSafe(NavController.kt:17)
        at com.m.marketplace.utils.ktx.NavControllerKt.navigateSafe$default(NavController.kt:13)
        at com.m.marketplace.utils.ktx.FragmentKt.navigate(Fragment.kt:15)
        at com.m.marketplace.ui.login.view.PreviousLoginDialog.goToHome(PreviousLoginDialog.kt:119)
        at com.m.marketplace.ui.login.view.PreviousLoginDialog.access$goToHome(PreviousLoginDialog.kt:28)
        at com.m.marketplace.ui.login.view.PreviousLoginDialog$firstInit$1.invoke(PreviousLoginDialog.kt:111)
        at com.m.marketplace.ui.login.view.PreviousLoginDialog$firstInit$1.invoke(PreviousLoginDialog.kt:28)
        at com.m.marketplace.ui.login.view.PreviousLoginDialog.onCreate(PreviousLoginDialog.kt:44)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
    E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2629)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2571)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1685)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:264)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1818)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView.<init>(FragmentContainerView.java:166)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:51)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1073)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1001)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
        at com.m.marketplace.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3286)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: You'll want to include the *entire* stack trace - it is usually the very bottom most "Caused by" that is the most important.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ClassNotFoundException when using androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009473/classnotfoundexception-when-using-androidx-fragment-app-fragmentcontainerview)

Comment: @SamChen No, this is different error

Comment: I have same issues( ClassNotFoundException and Error inflating class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView in my logs). It appeared after I added 1 argument in my nav_graph file. When I comment it everything works. Very strange. Argument is a custom Serializable class

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `Jetpack Compose` change `MainActivity` extends to `AppCompatActivity` instead of `CompatActivity`

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and I figured out that Android studio is not adding name tags in navigation graph. So, adding name tag in navigation graph xml worked for me.

In nav_graph.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.example.MyApp.fragments.LoginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_login"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
```

Or if you are not sure then switch to the design and in attributes tab on right side select the class name from drop-down list

[image: Name Tag in Design View]

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you have added ID to your nav graph and fragment container view. Also check fragment (declared asstart destination) does not have any instantiation issue.

Answer (score 0):

When using Koin, adding `android:name=".MyApplication"` in application in the manifest, fixed this error and the "Accessing hidden method" warnings that were appearing before the error

Answer (score 0):

check if the Activity you're working with is inherited from `AppCompatActivity` and not from regular `Activity`