# ClassNotFoundException when using SafeArgs with Proguard and Navigation Architecture Component?

Tags: android, proguard, navigation-architecture

I'm using `SafeArgs` plugin and `Navigation Architecture Component` but the app is crashing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.package.domain.models.Model"
```

I'm using `minifyEnabled true` in the Gradle.

Also, I have three modules `app`, `data`, and `domain`. So, in all three `proguard-rules` files I have added

```
-keepnames class com.package.domain.models.Model1
-keepnames class com.package.domain.types.ImageType
-keepnames class com.package.domain.models.Model
```

I'm using these three classes as `argType` in my Navigation graph.

But the app is still crashing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it ok when minifyEnabled false?

Comment: @hata yeah it is fine.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: @RobertNagy version of?

Comment: @hata yes it is okay with `minifyEnabled false`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the more appropriate thing to do would be adding this to add these in my `proguard-rules` file(s).

```
-keepnames class * extends android.os.Parcelable
-keepnames class * extends java.io.Serializable
```

As I don't have to keep annotating my models with `@Keep` which are `Parcelable` or `Serializable` or keeping the whole model package away from obfuscation.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378828/7436566) for more information.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the "extends" qualifier instead of "implements"? Either way from what I found they should be equivalent I guess: https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/usage#classspecification

Answer (score 2):

Try with putting `@Keep` annotation top of class. Like

```
import androidx.annotation.Keep

@Keep
data class RepoData(val id: Long, val name: String)
```

Comment: Thank you! but I think this answers my question better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378828/7436566

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the whole model package (it's usually alright to do it actually) like

```
-keep class com.package.domain.models.** { *; }
```

Comment: Thank you! but I think this answers my question better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378828/7436566

Answer (score -2):

Always use `@keep` annotation whenever you want the class to stay in memory .

@Keep
data class MyData(val id: long,val name: String)

Comment: Thank you! but I think this answers my question better. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50378828/7436566