# Fatal Exception: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState

Tags: android, proguard, android-appcompat, androidx

I am getting the below exception from the app I am using androidx with the latest compact Gradle version. This issue is basically happening with the signed bundle and reported in Firebase Crashlytics. Is there any solution to fix this crash issue?

```
Fatal Exception: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:3050)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2967)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2869)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:3252)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.initializeFromParcelLocked(BaseBundle.java:292)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:236)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.size(BaseBundle.java:364)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.hashCode(LaunchActivityItem.java:208)
   at java.util.AbstractList.hashCode(AbstractList.java:541)
   at java.util.Objects.hashCode(Objects.java:98)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ClientTransaction.hashCode(ClientTransaction.java:241)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutorHelper.tId(TransactionExecutorHelper.java:266)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:86)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2046)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

Comment: Maybe this link can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67168216/classnotfoundexception-when-using-safeargs-with-proguard-and-navigation-architec

Comment: Did you fixed this issue?