# Stop fragment re-creation on config change (different layouts for portrait and landscape)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-configchanges

Here is the layout design for my tablet portrait and landscape

- Portrait layout

  - Menu Navigation Drawer and
  - Content Fragment
- Landscape layout (Dual Pane)

  - Menu Fragment on the left
  - Content Fragment on the right

I am using support library for the navigation drawer `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

Usecase :

1. App launched in landscape mode
2. Landscape Layout - Dual Pane is inflated and data loaded
3. Orientation changed
4. Menu fragment destroyed and detached
5. Portrait Layout - Navigation Drawer with content fragment inflated
6. ***Navigation drawer attached to activity and detached immediately***
7. *** Because Landscape Menu Fragment is re-created by the system and attached to the activity.***
8. ***App crashes because Navigation Drawer is detached***

I tried a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519214/prevent-fragment-recovery-in-android#answer-15683289) suggested by a stackoverflow user [goRGon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519214/prevent-fragment-recovery-in-android#answer-15683289) and it seems to work.

***But need your suggestions whether this is the best way to stop a fragment recreation ?***

Comment: I wouldn't use the solution you linked to. From what I understood your scenario looks quite simple, something like this https://gist.github.com/luksprog/7c8523f3e3a0886081ec

Comment: I have a similar layout except for the fragment inside the drawer instead of framelayout. Would it make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it should make a difference.

Comment: Thanks Luksprog. Changing Fragment to FrameLayout doesn't help. Any suggestions

Comment: What I said above should work, I even made a small sample(basic stuff) https://github.com/luksprog/DrawerWithOrientation .I'm assuming that you get the exception due to the DrawerLayout not being in the landscape layout, which indeed need to be handled manually in code.