# How to prevent a child fragment to be automatically created after app restart?

Tags: android, android-fragments

My app has an Activity A, which contains a fragment B. In B, user clicks a button and a child fragment C is created in B. Now user backgrounds the app by pressing home button. After awhile my app is killed and restarted by Android OS.

Then user launches the app again. Now Activity A is started and both fragment B and its child fragment C are recreated automatically. My question, how to prevent child fragment C gets recreated automatically? I try to remove fragment C from B in B's onAttachFragment method during restarting, but it didn't work.

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment f) {
  super.onAttachFragment(f);
  if (isRestart) {
    getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .remove(f)
      .commit();
    isRestart = false;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prevent Fragment recovery in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519214/prevent-fragment-recovery-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I ended up with removing child fragment C from B in B's onActivityCreated(). After that, only C's onCreate() was called, onCreateView, onStart, onResume were not called.