# Unable to instantiate fragment - java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: android, fragment

Hy guys, i got this stack trace from my developer console. Okay i'm not sure what cause this crash. because i never get this error by my self when test my app and just got it from developer console in google play.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package.name/package.name.activity.SomeActivity}: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment package.name.photopreview.PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter$1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment streetdirectory.mobile.modules.photopreview.PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter$1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:399)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.instantiate(Fragment.java:97)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:1760)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:200)
at streetdirectory.mobile.modules.businessdetail.BusinessDetailActivity.onCreate(BusinessDetailActivity.java:134)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5188)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class streetdirectory.mobile.modules.photopreview.PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter$1; no empty constructor
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:388)
... 18 more
```

anybody can help me analyze this problem ? and give some useful suggestion to me . 
thanks, regards ..

**EDIT**

This is PhotoPreviewFragmentAdapter code.

```
public class PhotoPreviewFragmentAdapter<T extends ImageListServiceOutput> extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<T> mData = new ArrayList<T>();

    public PhotoPreviewFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<T> data) {
        mData = data;
    }


    @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        PhotoPreviewFragment view = new PhotoPreviewFragment() {

            @Override
            public ImageListServiceOutput getData() {
                if (position < mData.size()) {
                    return mData.get(position);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Add Photo Button
        //return mData.size()+1;
        return mData.size();
    }


}
```

give some clue about how to reproduce this crash may be will help me so much. thanks

**EDIT**

May be the problem is (just like **Streets Of Boston** said) the anonymous inner class in PhotoTumbnailFragmentAdapter, i used it in this method

```
public Fragment getItem(final int position) {
        PhotoThumbnailFragment view = new PhotoThumbnailFragment() {

            @Override
            public ImageListServiceOutput getData() {
                if (position < mData.size()) {
                    return mData.get(position);
                }
                return null;
            }

            public void onPhotoClicked(ImageListServiceOutput data) {

                if (mImageClickedListener != null) {
                    if (data != null) {
                        Logger.info("Photo Clicked");
                        mImageClickedListener.onImageClicked(data, position);
                    } else {
                        Logger.info("Add Photo Clicked");
                        mImageClickedListener.onAddImageClicked(position);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        return view;
    }
```

PhotoThumbnailFragment is an independent class btw.

Comment: Can you post your `PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter` code ?

Comment: You used annonymous PhotoPreviewFragment. You should not use annonymous fragment class. Change it into non-annonymous class. If you should access `mData`, you can access it by implementing setter method for `mData`

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have not defined empty constructor for your `PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter`.
Fragment should have an empty constructor like

```
public PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter(){
//empty constructor
}
```

Comment: is it a must to put an empty constructor in fragmentadapter ?

Comment: thank you i test all way but yours is workded for me 
thanks thanks thanks

Answer (score 4):

1. Make your `PhotoPreviewFragment` class a **public** and **static** class.
   Right now, your `PhotoPreviewFragment` is a non-static (i.e. it has an enclosing class, in your case the `PhotoPreviewFragmentAdapter` class) inner class, which cannot be publicly instantiated.
2. Be sure to have a public empty constructor public `PhotoPreviewFragment()  {... ...}`.

Solution:
Refactor your `PhotoPreviewFragment` to a proper public static inner class or just a public class in its own Java file.
Be sure to add a public empty constructor.

Comment: (1). my Fragment is not an inner class. it an independent java class (one .java file)

(2). i have added an empty constructor, but still get the same error.

Comment: In your code example in your original question, your fragment is an inner class. Its non-public(/anonymous) class name is "PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter$1" The '$1' at the end hints at it being an non-public class and it is clear from your code it's an inner non-public class.

Comment: mmmm i've edited my question, can u look at that ? may be you can give me some advice how to solve this. so i have 2 java files here, PhotoThumbnailFragment.java and PhotoThumbnailFragmentAdapter.java

Comment: But you subclassed PhotoThumbnailFragment into a new inner anonymous sub-class: "view = new PhotoThumbnailFragment() { ... ... };" You need to create a new static public sub-class of PhotoThumbnailFragment instead, that overrides these two methods (getData and onPhotoClicked).

Answer (score 3):

can't comment hence posting as an answer, please go through this link may be this will help [Fragment - InstantiationException: no empty Constructor -> Google Maps v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062923/fragment-instantiationexception-no-empty-constructor-google-maps-v2)

and this

[Do fragments really need an empty constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor)