# No View Found for ID when "Don't Keep Activities" Is Turned On

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-view

My app was crashing intermittently after some inactivity. So i figured I wasn't storing things correctly. I turned on "Don't Keep Activities" to troubleshoot and now my app is crashing everywhere.

Stack trace: https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/6d41fee54b1e129b7922
This is the layout that goes missing: https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/73ace0c99ae675023e0f

Comment: "Performing pause of activity that is not resumed" are you calling directly onPause()?

Comment: @DiogoBento no. nowhere.

Comment: neither onCreate, onResume and onDestroy? are you shure?

Comment: I'm calling onResume() and onDestroy()

Comment: yeah. why are you doing it? you should not do that. The Android system is responsible for the call of this methods.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/hanleyhansen/932ecf248ee2c75d39c5

Comment: Can you point me to any documentation to support that? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: but that's ok. you should allyways call the `super` on this methods

Comment: So you don't think that's the issue?

Comment: no, that's not the issue.

Comment: could you post your activity code?

Comment: sorry, I cannot help you. But I think you should learn some things. First, "Good code is its own best documentation.". Next, "In extreme cases, the system might simply kill your app process without calling the activity’s final onDestroy() callback, so it’s important you use onStop() to release resources that might leak memory."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are experiencing a likely symptom of [Issue 19917](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917).  This bug exists in 3.2 and higher and was only fixed recently (4.2).  This same fix hasn't made its way in to the support library, yet.

Check out [comment 28](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917#c28) for a real fix: you'll want to edit your support library and recompile.  edit v4/java/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.java

```
Bundle saveFragmentBasicState(Fragment f) {
    Bundle result = null;

    if (mStateBundle == null) {
        mStateBundle = new Bundle();
    }
    f.onSaveInstanceState(mStateBundle);
    if (!mStateBundle.isEmpty()) {
        result = mStateBundle;
        mStateBundle = null;
    }

    if (f.mView != null) {
        saveFragmentViewState(f);
    }
    if (f.mSavedViewState != null) {
        if (result == null) {
            result = new Bundle();
        }
        result.putSparseParcelableArray(
                FragmentManagerImpl.VIEW_STATE_TAG, f.mSavedViewState);
    }
    if (!f.mUserVisibleHint) {
        // Only add this if it's not the default value
        // @@@ BUG, result may not have been created, can be null!
        if (result == null) {
            result = new Bundle();
        }
        result.putBoolean(FragmentManagerImpl.USER_VISIBLE_HINT_TAG, f.mUserVisibleHint);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If you dont feel up to the task and want to wait for Google to fix the support library
here is another workaround 
[Comment 8](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917#c8) for fix you can apply to all your fragments

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //first saving my state, so the bundle wont be empty.
        //http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19917
        outState.putString("WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_KEY", "WORKAROUND_FOR_BUG_19917_VALUE");
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

I've also come across `transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();`  as a "fix" for this instead of `transaction.commit();`

Some other background info and workaround I've found that are related that helped me with fragment issues (esp. when nesting them)

- TNR's answer to [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState with DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262359/794088)  (decent workaround)
- How to fix “Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState” on Android Fragments ][4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14262359/794088) (very informative)
- Chris Jenkins answer to [Do fragments really need an empty constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450535/794088)