# Reference to fragment from child fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragment (A) with viewpager. Viewpager contains FragmentStatePagerAdapter with fragments(B, C, D...). How I can get reference to fragment(A) from fragments(B, C, D...) in viewpager?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18706941/fragment-with-viewpager-inside-fragment-and-fragmentstatepageradapter-results-in). it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep references of your fragments at `instantiateItem` in `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Elaborated answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager).

Comment: @DarkDarker hm, maybe this could help: getParentFramgent http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getParentFragment()

Comment: Can you explain your answer. The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager) in your answer is about how to get child fragment from viewpager. The OP is asking how to get reference to parent fragment A from viewpager fragments B,C,D.