# error: this class should provide a default constructor, when creating apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm experiencing this error when building the apk: this class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments)

I have searched for this error and a solution is to change the class name, I tried but the error occurs with others classes and after change the name of some classes comeback to the first one, I am in a bucle.

The first class I have the error is this

CustomaAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<Juegos> juegoslist = null;
private ArrayList<Juegos> arraylist;


public CustomAdapter(Context context,
                     List<Juegos> juegoslist) {

    this.context = context;
    this.juegoslist = juegoslist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Juegos>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(juegoslist);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

}
```

I can run the app in a device without problems but I can't create the apk. Someone can help me with this issue?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Just add an empty constructor

Comment: The error message would seem to be fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: Pedro, answer maybe?

Comment: Best Solution Works for me [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420637/error-non-default-constructors-in-fragments/39608360#39608360)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you override the constructor, the class understand that it doesn't exist anymore, because you are only defining the modified one.
To resolve it just place an empty constructor in the class:

`public CustomAdapter(){}`

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, it works. I had the problem in four classes, adding this code to every class, problem solved,

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a empty constructor for `CustomAdapter` class. Your final code should be like,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


// Declare Variables
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ImageLoader imageLoader;
private List<Juegos> juegoslist = null;
private ArrayList<Juegos> arraylist;

// empty constructor
public CustomAdapter() {

} 

public CustomAdapter(Context context,
                     List<Juegos> juegoslist) {

    this.context = context;
    this.juegoslist = juegoslist;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Juegos>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(juegoslist);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(context);

}
```