# Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (AppName.CustomListAdapter) [Instantiatable]

Tags: constructor, apk, adapter, signed, custom-lists

I am trying to create a signed apk for my application but i get an error after clicking finish after the create a signed apk dialogue.

> Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (MYAPPNAME.CustomListAdapter) [Instantiatable]

Java code below

```
     import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    //TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
   // extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

Help Please

Comment: Best Solution work for me [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420637/error-non-default-constructors-in-fragments/39608360#39608360)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved in the build.gradle file. Inside the android string add the following:

```
  lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
        }
```