# Want to pass data from MainActivity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Here's my code in 
MainActivity.java

```
ViewFragment fr = new ViewFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String val="sonali";
bundle.putString("myname", val);
fr.setArguments(bundle);
return fr;
```

In my ViewFragment.java the code for retrieving data in `onActivityCreated()` is..

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
String val = bundle.getString("myname");
if (val == null) {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "arguments is null " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "text " + val , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It gives null. Can any one help me.

Comment: can you please tell me how are you adding fragment in fragment manager?

Comment: pls update your Fragment transaction code.

Comment: [Send data from activity to fragment in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set a new instance metho for your fragment (I think it's the easiest way) and things as user name can be saved in usersettings (SharedPref).

```
static final ViewFragment newInstance(String myName) {
    //TODO: Save myName
}}
```

Comment: Check this : [You shouldn't add constructors to fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor)

Answer (score 0):

a) Activity -> Fragment

In your activity : create a bundle and use

```
     fragment.setArguments(bundle)
```

in your fragment : use

```
     Bundle bundle = getArguments()
```

2) fragment -> Activity

In your fragment : create un interface with getter and setter methods (callback methods)
In your activity : implement the interface
3) fragment -> Activity

In your activity : Create public getter and setter or other methods
In your fragment : called public activity getter, setter or other methods using :

```
    getActivity().getSomething(), getActivity().setSomething(args) or getActivity().someMethod(args)
```

4) activity -> fragment

In your fragment : create a public method

In your activity : call an active fragment public method :

```
    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment).publicMethod(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it & it works fine. In activity `onCreate` method add

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("my_key","my_value");
    ViewFragment fg = new ViewFragment();
    fg.setArguments(bundle);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, fg)
                .commit();
    }
```

In `fragment` on `onActivityCreated` add

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        String value = bundle.getString("my_key");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I add this code but it says."The method add(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, ViewFragment)".can you pls help.