# Programatically creating and populating viewpager fragment. result is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment

I am going through the Android Developer guide on View Paging with fragments and am stuck at populating the fragment from my main onCreate method. I think I am confused as to what methods get called when to populate the fragment as I am getting null values.

My Fragment Class

```
public class CatalogFragment extends Fragment {
    private String filename;
    private String author;
    private String title;

    public CatalogFragment(String f, String t, String a){
        filename = f;
        author = a;
        title = t;
        Log.d("frag", f+" | "+t+" | "+a);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.catalog_fragment,  container, false);
        ImageView imgView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgFrag);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
        imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        TextView txtView = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        txtView.setText(author+": "+title);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_view);

    //Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    //populate the fragment
    //I was thinking I could pass the fragment class the necessary information to put an imageview and text view in place.

    List<Poster> posters = db.getAllPosters();
    for (Poster p : posters) {
        final String filename = p.getPosterFilename();

    //Create a new Fragment?
        new CatalogFragment(filename, p.getPosterTitle(), p.getPresenterFname()+" "+p.getPresenterLname());

    }

}
```

However it appears that getItem is what is actually being called to populate the fragment. I think. If I put null in for the arguments that is what I get. If I try to omit this line eclipse starts to complatin. So I am stuck.

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position){
            return new CatalogFragment(null, null, null);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Adapter is what creates the fragments in the view pager, you do not need to create them yourself.

Here is what the Adapter and Activity#onCreate could look like to give you the correct result.

Notice how we are telling the adapter where to get it's data.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog_view);

    //Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter
    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPagetAdapter.setData(db.getAllPosters()); // Provide Poster Data to Adapter
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}
```

In the adapter we tell it how to build it's fragments:

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    List<Poster> posterList = new ArrayList<Poster>(0);
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public void setData(List<Poster> posters) {
        posterList.addAll(posters);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){
        Poster poster = posterList.get(position)
        // FRAGMENTS SHOULD NOT IMPLEMENT A CONTRUCTOR!!!
        // This will lead to other issue down the line.
        return new CatalogFragment(poster.getPosterFilename(), poster.getPosterTitle(), poster.getPresenterFname()+" "+poster.getPresenterLname());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return posterList.size();
    }

}
```

```

As a side-note, you should not have a fragment constructor with arguments. See this other SO question for an explanation: [Do fragments really need an empty constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor)

Comment: So this solves my problem but it is not the best strategy correct? The SO answer you provided looks pretty in depth. I am going to have to study it for a bit. Thank you for the help!!!!

Comment: For some reason I am Eclipse is telling me that the method setData is never used and in my onCreate it says the method setData is undefined...`mPagerAdapter.setData(db.getAllPosters());` : ` public void setData(List<Poster> posters){
   posterList.addAll(posters);
  }`

Comment: Ensure that the `mPagerAdapter` variable is of type `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and that should fix the undefined method error. The key to remember about the view pager is that it will call getItem based on the number returned by the adapter's `getCount`.

Comment: Eclipse said "The method setData(List<Poster>) is undefined for the type PagerAdapter" and told me to add cast to mPagerAdapter which worked. `((ScreenSlidePagerAdapter) mPagerAdapter).setData(db.getAllPosters());` I don't really understand why it would not have access to setData. I have it just like you show in your answer.