# Pass data to fragment edittext from activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Before you start answering i tried sharing  data using sharedpreferences ... i tried bundle thing but still having null values and application crushes, my application is a draw menu when you click on listview item it brings a fragment in front where i have several edittext textviews , when i click on a edittext to change text it works perfect , the problem is that the edittext  is initialy blank and it must load data from the main activity and this where i got NULL

[MainActivity ]
onCreate method

```
EditText     editus_ername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
            editus_ername.setText("Username");
```

[fragment class]

```
EditText editus_ername;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);

            editus_ername = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editUserName);


        return rootView;


    }




12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.WhatsHotFragment.onCreateView(WhatsHotFragment.java:40)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:441)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-14 12:32:48.699: E/AndroidRuntime(1517):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I don't know if I understood you. You are trying to pass data from an edit text in your activity to be shown in an edit text in your fragment ?

Comment: no accessing an edit text located at fragment layout , but i need to manipulate its value, the data i need to insert are located inside the main activity got it now?

Comment: no not really, so there is an activity with an edit text, you want to pass that edittext's value and show it in another edittext that is located inside the fragment, is that right ?

Comment: i have a MainActivity , i have a fragment class and fragment layout.
i have edittext inthe fragment layout it's empty .
i want to assign it a value when i call the fragment from the MainActivity .i hope you got it

Comment: what is WhatsHotFragment.java line 40?

Comment: editus_ername.setText(_userName);

Comment: yes got it, check out my answer, i hope it helps.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try send your String by fragment constructor or a new public method.

for example by constructor:

Fragment Class:

```
String _userName;
EditText editus_ername;

public FragmentClassName(String userName){
_userName = userName;
}



   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);

            editus_ername = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editUserName);

            editus_ername.setText(_userName);

        return rootView;


    }
```

MainActivity:

```
new FragmentClassName("Username");
```

Comment: can you post your Log?

Comment: [fragments need a empty constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor)

Comment: well it worked for me , but change
 (EditText)getActivity().findViewById( );

with

 (EditText)view.findViewById( );

Answer (score 1):

you are calling the edittext using getactivity, change this like;

```
 editus_ername = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
```

with;

```
 editus_ername = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
```

and if you want to pass values from your activity to the fragment, in Activity.java use;

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("value", value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and in fragment.java use;

```
value= getArguments().getString("value");
```

Comment: thank you for the help i just changed the getActivity() with rootView (or simply the view ) and it works

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fragment class, if the `EditText` is located in your `R.layout.fragment_whats_hot` layout, so do this  instead :

```
editus_ername = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editUserName);
```

And if you want to pass data to your fragment class, from your main activity:

1. You can use `arguments`
2. Or create a method inside your fragment :

   public void test(int value) {
       // do stuff
   }

And call this method inside main activity.

Here is a [link from the doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver)

Comment: i tried the bundle method i always get null values when declare
editus_ername = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editUserName);

Comment: that means that your edit text is not defined inside this layout. Paste your layout's content so !