# Unable to initialize nested Fragment due to it being abstract on rotation

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, constructor, nested

I have the following object hierarchy:

```
          BaseMessageListFragment (abstract)
                 ^
                 |
                 /\
                /  \
               /    \
              /      \
             /        \
            /          \
           /            \
          /              \
         |                |
SwapMessageListFragment  RequestMessageListFragment
```

Now, each of these fragments (`SwapMessageListFragment` and `RequestMessageListFragment`) is actually nested within another `Fragment`. Taking, for example, the case of `SwapMessageListFragment`, it's nested within a class called `SwapDetailFragment`.

This works fine, but when I change orientation when `SwapDetailFragment` is displayed, I get the following crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.ui.shift.ShiftDetailActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #57: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.app.ui.shift.fragment.SwapDetailFragment.onCreateView(SwapDetailFragment.java:559)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1929)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
            at com.example.app.ui.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:161)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.example.app.ui.message.fragment.BaseMessageListFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:432)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:396)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2162)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:177)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.app.ui.shift.fragment.SwapDetailFragment.onCreateView(SwapDetailFragment.java:559)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1929)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
            at com.example.app.ui.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:161)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: class com.example.app.ui.message.fragment.BaseMessageListFragment cannot be instantiated
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1587)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:421)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:396)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2162)
            at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:177)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at com.example.app.ui.shift.fragment.SwapDetailFragment.onCreateView(SwapDetailFragment.java:559)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1120)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1929)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:547)
            at com.example.app.ui.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.java:161)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3947)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1309)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Since `BaseMessageListFragment` is abstract, I'm not sure why it's trying to initialize this `Fragment`. I originally had a reference to a member variable in `SwapDetailFragment` called `mMessageFrag` which was defined as follows:

```
private BaseMessageListFragment mMessageFrag;
```

I've tried making this a `SwapMessageListFragment` instead, but with no luck. Additionally, I've tried adding default constructors to `BaseMessageListFragment` (which seems a waste, since it can't be instantiated, anyway), `SwapMessageListFragment`, and `RequestMessageListFragment`, but, again, with no joy. Finally, I even attempted to create a `newInstance()` implementation on `BaseMessageListFragment` like the following:

```
  public static BaseMessageListFragment newInstance(Class<? extends GsonBase> aBaseObjectType,
                                                    long aBaseObjectId) {
    BaseMessageListFragment retVal;

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    // Add arguments here
    retVal.setArguments(args);

    return retVal;
  }
```

(as advised in [Do fragments really need an empty constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor) ), but still with no luck.

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly that causes Android to want to instantiate the base class, rather than a derived class.

**EDIT**:

As requested, here is a view of the `fragment_swap_detail.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/request_header" style="@style/Material.View.Detail.Header" android:paddingTop="0dp" android:paddingBottom="0dp">
            <include android:id="@+id/swap_block" layout="@layout/list_item_request_block" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="59dp" 
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bar_background"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="10dp">
            <Button style="@style/Material.Widget.Button.Green" android:id="@+id/button_approve"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="38dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:text="Approve" />
            <Button style="@style/Material.Widget.Button.Red" android:id="@+id/button_decline"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="38dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:text="Decline" />
            <Button style="@style/Material.Widget.Button" android:id="@+id/button_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dp" 
                android:layout_height="38dp" 
                android:layout_weight="1" 
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <View android:layout_width="6dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#CCCCCC" />
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_listview"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_listview"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView style="@style/Material.View.Detail.Row.Header" android:id="@+id/tableheader_messages" android:text="Messages" />

            <EditText android:id="@+id/swap_message"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text|textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine" />

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_messages"
                android:name="com.example.app.ui.message.fragment.BaseMessageListFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView style="@style/Material.View.Detail.Row.Header" android:id="@+id/tableheader_takers" android:text="Potential Takers" />
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_check"
                android:name="com.example.app.ui.base.list.BaseCheckListFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your exception says there is an issue during xml inflation.. can you show your xml layout for that orientation where it crashes?

Comment: Sure. One second, let me edit the post.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize the layout file specified the `Fragment` directly. Do you think it might be better to make this section a `RelativeLayout` (or `LinearLayout`) as a placeholder, and inflate/load the fragment into the layout within the appropriate implementing class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can inflate an abstract `Fragment` via XML. Replace your fragment with a `FrameLayout` and use `FragmentManager` to load a fragment to that layout in runtime.

You should do that only once. After screen rotation your `savedInstanceState` won't be `null`, so your fragment will be there - `FragmentManager` handles that for you.

Comment: Oh! No wonder this is wonky. These xml files were _only_ in `layout-land`. :facepalm: