# Difference between fragment instantiation;

Tags: android-fragments, static, instantiation

I want to understand correctly the difference between these ways of get a fragment from constructor:

## 1

```
public MyFragment(DataClass data) {
this.dataClass = data;
}
```

## 2

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(DataClass data) {
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
fragment.setDataClass(data);
return fragment;
}
```

## 3

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(DataClass data) {
MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("myData", data.getData());
fragment.setArguments(args);

return fragment;
}
```

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `Fragment` should have empty constructor only!
Please check [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Fragment()), there is stated:
"**Every** fragment must have an empty constructor...".
Then check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor) for nice explanation.

About options ##2 and 3 - as for me, both are appropriate.
Via `Bundle` - again post mentioned above says, "This way if detached and re-attached the object state can be stored through the arguments.".

But if you create `newInstance` of `Fragment` every time - #2 approach is also good. I use #2 approach, cause I don't store created fragments.