# Android - ListFragment, empty bundle,

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, bundle, android-listfragment

I was trying to pass parameters to my fragment [in the way described here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor) But I have a problem, I get empty bundle (null) every time. Fragment gets connected first in setContentView, then it gets replaced using newInstance (everything works fine there, bundle is created, added and returned in fragment). In both cases in onCreate I get empty bundle. When created at beginning it should be empty, but after replacing with fragment with added bundle in newInstance it shouldn't.

Any ideas?

ListFragment

```
public class LeftListFragment extends ListFragment {


    private FragmentConnector connector;
    private FragmentConnector.listType type;

    public static final LeftListFragment newInstance(ArrayList<String> values) {
        LeftListFragment llf = new LeftListFragment();

        final Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putStringArrayList("values", values);
        llf.setArguments(bdl);

        return llf;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle bd1) {
        super.onCreate(bd1);

        if (bd1 != null) {
            List<String> tempList = getArguments().getStringArrayList("values");

            //due to JVM optimizations, using new String[0] is better than new String[list.size()]
            String[] values = tempList.toArray(new String[0]);


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, values);

            setListAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

MenuActivity

```
public class MenuActivity  extends Activity implements FragmentConnector {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("hello");

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.leftListFragment  ,LeftListFragment.newInstance(list))
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        }
```

MenuActivity Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Menu.MenuActivity"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/leftListFragment"
        class="com.buczel.attapp.Menu.LeftListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        tools:layout="@layout/rowlayout">

    </fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bd1` and `getArguments()` aren't the same thing. `bd1` is actually `savedInstanceState`.
If you check `bd1 != null` then of course there's no saved instance state the first time you start a Fragment. That'd be not null if, for instance, there's a change in the device orientation.
On the other hand, `getArguments()` is set only at first start when the arguments you set in the constructor are passed.

Just remove that `if (bd1 != null)` and you should be good to go.

Comment: You are right! Thanks! Changing to  if(getArguments()!=null) { ... } solved problem. Of course it made new one... There is locked loading gif on bottom of fragment o.0

Comment: is it a `ProgressBar` you put there for loading purposes?

Comment: Nope, it looks like it is waiting for rest of fragment to load. Something build in ListFragment I think. It looks like that: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/images/spinner1.jpg

Comment: Adding setListShown(true);
 in public void onViewCreated fixed it :) Thanks again!