# Communication between multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've a "A" fragment as follows (recyclerview):
https://img.exs.lv/e/z/ezeliitis/frags.png

1. How should I effectively duplicate fragment "A" with different images/text (same layout) and make fragment "B"?
2. How should I implement Database information and storage? For instance, I'll have fragments "A" category - 'GAMES'. When I click it, it should transfer to duplicate fragment "B", where it has "Basketball", "Football" ect... Also. If I click the fragments picture, it should show a small square with short information. Should I just make 3 seperate tables? How to link Fragments A - Fragment B - Detail information?
3. Also, if I've categories in Fragment "A" as following: cars/food/girls and I click food, then it goes to Fragment "B" which holds pizza/drinks ect - how to make sure fragment B gives right information according to fragment A (make sure it doesnt give from fragment 'a' (food) a result of fragment 'b' which holds information about cars for instance, which would be wrong)?

Answer (score -1):

You can use manual *constructors* for passing data from **fragment A** to **fragment B**.

```
public class fragB extends Fragment{

    int type;

    public fragB(){
        this.type = DEFAULT_TYPE;
    }

    public fragB(int type){
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

From **fragment A** do this to define your **fragB**

```
Fragment f = new fragB(TYPE_CAR);
```

or

```
Fragment f = new fragB(TYPE_FOOD);
```

**Note**: Empty constructor is just for resolving *exception*.

Comment: No. This is bad. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor

Comment: @cricket_007 An empty constructor assigning default value to **type** can resolve the errors.

Comment: It's still better to use the Fragment arguments bundle

Comment: @cricket_007 But Why?

Comment: If the Fragment is destroyed by the OS, you lose that value as the default constructor will be called, but the current arguments will be kept