# KOTLIN -> InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I am using kotlin in my android app and got this crash report:

```
android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment DetailsFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public.
```

Here is my DetailsFragment class.

```
class DetailsFragment() : Fragment() {

private var workflowId: String? = null
private var workflowData: WorkflowData? = null
private var releaseAtStr: String? = null

public fun init(workflowId: String,
                workflowData: WorkflowData,
                releaseAtStr: String? = null) {
    this.workflowId = workflowId
    this.workflowData = workflowData
    this.releaseAtStr = releaseAtStr
}

private var context: BaseActivity? = null

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    if (context is BaseActivity?) {
        this.context = context
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) =
        inflater?.inflate(R.layout.fragment_approval_details, container, false)

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    loadingOverlay?.show()
    populateWorkflowHistory()
}
```

}

Any idea how to fix it or at least reproduce?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to call constructor in your fragment:

```
class DetailsFragment : Fragment() {

private var workflowId: String? = null
private var workflowData: WorkflowData? = null
private var releaseAtStr: String? = null

public fun init(workflowId: String,
                workflowData: WorkflowData,
                releaseAtStr: String? = null) {
    this.workflowId = workflowId
    this.workflowData = workflowData
    this.releaseAtStr = releaseAtStr
}
```

Comment: How do mean this? I am quite new. Can you please explain more?

Comment: I just removed the ( ) from after DetailsFragment :)

Comment: That's the constructor

Comment: That means that the constructor from Fragment will be called, am I right? But if I left (), the functionality is the same, just the DetailsFragment constructor call Fragment constructor...

Comment: There's an explanation here to why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor/10450535#10450535 you shouldn't override the constructor in fragments. If you don't declare a constructor for you fragment, a default empty one will be created for you satisfying the requirements stated in the exception