# Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.Screen

Tags: android, react-native, androidx

I have been developing an app for android and ios using React Native 0.60.4, and just recently I discovered that putting the app in split-screen or freeform mode (from being the only app on the screen) sometimes causes it to crash.

I played with this further and found that I can launch the app into split screen or freeform mode with no problem, but sometimes resizing it will cause it to crash. Below is the output from my debugger instance in Android Studio, which I'm struggling to make sense of:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myApp, PID: 32150
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myApp/com.myApp.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.Screen$ScreenFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.Screen$ScreenFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:465)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:50)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:80)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:3109)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:344)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:443)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:50) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:80) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:3109) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:344) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:51) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Screen fragments should never be restored
        at com.swmansion.rnscreens.Screen$ScreenFragment.<init>(Screen.java:24)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:443) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:50) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:80) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(FragmentManager.java:3109) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState(FragmentController.java:158) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:344) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:85) 
        at com.facebook.react.ReactActivity.onCreate(ReactActivity.java:51) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5187) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Comment: Have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor)

Comment: Yea, that was the first search result i checked, but it wasn't the exact same issue as mine from what I could tell

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Add this to your MainActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(null);
   }
```

Comment: Your issue is with React native Screen which at the moment has a problem with instantiating fragments. To avoid that set super.onCreate to null.  https://github.com/kmagiera/react-native-screens/issues/17#issuecomment-424704067

Comment: Which is the difference between using the line "super.onCreate(null);" and "super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);"?

Comment: If I do this, my React layout doesn't get redrawn. How can I restore that?

Comment: This also fixed the crash I had when the device was switched from dark/light theme modes on Android

Answer (score 12):

In `MainActivity.java` add

```
import android.os.Bundle;
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(null);
}
```

Explanation: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens#android

Example:

```
package com.example_app;

import android.os.Bundle; // required for onCreate parameter
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "example_app";
  }

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
      return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach:

```
context.supportFragmentManager.addFragmentOnAttachListener { _,_ -> context.savedStateRegistry.unregisterSavedStateProvider("android:support:fragments")}
```

Comment: Where do i add this line?