# React native App crashes when changing into light to dark mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

My React native app's system dark mode works fine in ios, However in android it is crashing and showing app stops working. I have attached the logcat for the reference.

```
    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:516)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
        at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:311)
        at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference
        at com.onesignal.OSUtils.packageInstalledAndEnabled(OSUtils.java:275)
        at com.onesignal.OSUtils.isGMSInstalledAndEnabled(OSUtils.java:288)
        at com.onesignal.OSUtils.supportsGooglePush(OSUtils.java:330)
        at com.onesignal.OSUtils.getDeviceType(OSUtils.java:349)
        at com.onesignal.OSUtils.isAndroidDeviceType(OSUtils.java:371)
        at com.onesignal.LocationController.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(LocationController.java:337)
        at com.onesignal.LocationController.onFocusChange(LocationController.java:325)
        at com.onesignal.OneSignal.onAppLostFocus(OneSignal.java:1308)
        at com.onesignal.OSFocusHandler$Companion.onLostFocusDoWork(OSFocusHandler.kt:139)
        at com.onesignal.OSFocusHandler$OnLostFocusWorker.doWork(OSFocusHandler.kt:118)
        at androidx.work.Worker$1.run(Worker.java:86)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) 
2022-04-10 00:04:17.649 20348-21057/com.myapp E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 79(JVMTI_ERROR_UNMODIFIABLE_CLASS)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is the answer that saved my time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57709742/unable-to-instantiate-fragment-com-swmansion-rnscreens-screen#:%7E:text=this%20to%20your-,MainActivity,-.java)

I am very thankful to the answer holder

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SplashScreen.show(this); 
    super.onCreate(null);
  }
Adding this in mainactivity.java saved my day.
```