# Android fragment onCreateView delayed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

**Background & Problem:**

I have a custom `Fragment` class. I reuse this fragment class for multiple status displays. In the parent `Activity`, I load the fragment and call a method on the fragment to set some text, etc. When I do this, I hit a `NullPointerException`. The reason is [onCreateView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle)) has not yet been called, i.e. the view doesn't exist, thus accessing a `TextView` to call `.setText(String)` will ofcourse run into a `NullPointerException`.

*Fragment Class*

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.example.app.R;

public class CopyStaticFragment extends Fragment {

    private String initialActionText, initialSecondaryText, initialTitleText;
    private TextView textViewTitle, textViewSecondary;
    private Button btnAction;
    private View.OnClickListener actionCallback;

    public void setActionButtonListener(View.OnClickListener actionCallback) {
        this.actionCallback = actionCallback;
    }

    public CopyStaticFragment() {
    }

    public CopyStaticFragment(View.OnClickListener actionCallback) {
        this.actionCallback = actionCallback;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_status, container, false);

        textViewTitle = layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
        textViewTitle.setText(initialTitleText);
        textViewSecondary = layout.findViewById(R.id.textViewSecondary);
        textViewSecondary.setText(initialSecondaryText);
        btnAction = layout.findViewById(R.id.btnAction);
        btnAction.setText(initialActionText);
        btnAction.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(actionCallback != null) {
                actionCallback.onClick(v);
            }
        });

        return layout;
    }

    public void setPrimaryText(String text) {
        textViewTitle.setText(text);
    }

    public void setSecondaryText(String text) {
        textViewSecondary.setText(text);
    }

    public void setActionText(String text) {
        btnAction.setText(text);
    }

    public void setInitialActionText(String text) {
        this.initialActionText = text;
    }

    public void setInitialSecondaryText(String text) {
        this.initialSecondaryText = text;
    }

    public void setInitialTitleText(String text) {
        this.initialTitleText = text;
    }

}
```

Somewhere in my main activity, as a callback response from a `Service` status, I will do something like:

```
if (instance.getUnbackedUpCount() > 0) {
    // Load first fragment - i.e. we can backup content
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameCurrentStatus, copyStartFragment)
            .commit();
    capacityControlFragment.setInfoIconVisible(true);
} else {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameCurrentStatus, copyFinishFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

where `copyStartFragment` & `copyFinishFragment` are instances of the above mentioned fragment.

*Note:*

*Depending on the `Service` status update interval, the call to `replace()` fragments can be almost instantaneous - which I figure is the actual problem.*

**My workaround:**

Is to have *initial* setters for all views and their properties. e.g. `initialTitleText`, `initialMessageText`, `initialActionButtonText`, `initialActionButtonVisibility`, etc. I feel this is hack'ish and not inline with the intended design philisophy of Fragment use.

**My Question**

Is this a design problem on my part for encountering such an error or is there a workaround to call the `onCreateView()` sooner?

Comment: `public CopyStaticFragment(View.OnClickListener actionCallback) {` unless you are also using `FragmentFactory` which you probably aren't, you should be getting a lint error that your app will crash in horrible ways if you do this. All of your `set*` methods should be passed in with `Bundle arguments` using `fragment.setArguments(Bundle)`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for the advice. The set* methods were only put as a  temporary measure - will implement bundle if no solution to the main problem is given. Also, would you kindly explain the callback issue in the constructor?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10450535/2413303

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that is very helpful, thank you. Also, it appears the solution mentioned in your comment above also includes this 'workaround' I am using. i.e. Setting these values before hand - so the `onCreateView()` delay appears to be an actual issue.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce would you mind posting this as a solution with a bit more detail - need to give credit where it is due.

Comment: you can setText in onViewCreated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.commit()` as part of replacing fragments.
This is done async. No way around it, it's just how that function works.

You can use `.commitNow()`, and it will be done sync.
By doing it like this, you should be able to access the views instantly after the function returns.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#commitNow()

Comment: ah yes, `commitNow()`. It seems like this is not recommended if there are other pending transactions for the fragment manager. I will rather settle for @EpicPandaForce's solution in the question comment section as a safer option.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the initial strings to the fragment using the ***recommended*** way to initialise a fragment:

```
public static CopyStaticFragment newInstance(String initialString....) {
    CopyStaticFragment fragment = new CopyStaticFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(INITIAL_STRING, initialString);

    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Then in `onCreate`:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mInitialString = getArguments().getString(INITIAL_STRING);
    }
}
```

Then when you set your `TextView` text in `OnViewCreated` the string and any other parameters are available.

Initialise your fragment in the activity using:

```
CopyStaticFragment.newInstance("initial string",....);
```

Side note: `onCreateView` should only be used to inflate your layout resource, use `OnViewCreated` to initialise your views after the layout has been inflated.

Stay as far away as you can from `commitNow()` and `popBackStackImmediate()` unless you love `IllegalStateException`