# Koin FragmentFactory fails to handle activity re-creation

Tags: koin, koin-scope

I am using the latest Koin version `3.1.2`. I have a basic `Fragment` that accepts a String parameter to it's constructor.

My Koin setup is as follows:

Activity:

```
override val scope: Scope by activityScope()
private val fragment by inject<MyFragment> {
    parametersOf(intent.getStringExtra(PROJECT_ID_EXTRA))
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setupKoinFragmentFactory(scope)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    .
    .
}
```

Fragment:

```
class MyFragment(private val projectId: String?) : BaseFragment() {

}
```

Koin Module:

```
scope<MyActivity> {
    fragment { (projectId: String) -> MyFragment(projectId) }
}
```

To simulate activity re-creation, I have turned on `Don't keep activities` flag in the developer options.

What always happens when activity is re-created, I get the following exception:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.activity.MyActivity}: org.koin.core.error.InstanceCreationException: Could not create instance for [Factory:'com.fragment.MyFragment',scope:q:'com.activity.MyActivity']
```

```
Can't get injected parameter #0 from DefinitionParameters[] for type 'java.lang.String'
```

Comment: Fragments should have empty constructor, this has nothing to do with Koin. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do fragments really need an empty constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor)

Comment: @TorkelVelure What you are saying is true if I wasn't using Fragment Factory. In my case I should not need an empty constructor