# How to send data from Activity to Fragment using Interface and without the transaction?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to send the data from `MainActivity` to `Fragment` but i don't want to pass the data in the arguments when i am making the transaction to the fragment like below:

```
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString("name", name)
val fragment = BlankFragment(this)
fragment.arguments = bundle
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentView, fragment).commit()
```

I want to pass the data from the `activity` to the `fragment` using the `interface`. I am able to send the data from the fragment to the activity using the interface but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You have an instance of a fragment in `fragment`, so provided it has a property `name` you can just say `fragment.name = "name"`.

Note that when the app is restarted by the system after it is killed, the system will try to restore the fragment by calling it with empty constructor. So you [can't have a constructor that have arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450348/do-fragments-really-need-an-empty-constructor), and also you won't get a `name` if you set it using `fragment.name = "name"`. Using a bundle ensures that that the fragment gets its arguments after restart.

Comment: Are you trying to say that we can't send data from Activity to Fragment using Interfaces?

Comment: What exactly do you understand by an interface?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can resolve your issue

Adding fragment to Activity

```
 val interfaceCall:FetchDataInterface = DataFragment.newInstance("data")
        interfaceCall.getData("data from interface")
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame, DataFragment.newInstance("data"))
            .commit()
```

Fragment Class

```
class DataFragment : Fragment(),MainActivity.FetchDataInterface {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    arguments?.let {
        param1 = it.getString(DATA)
        Log.e("checkParam", " : $param1")
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_data, container, false)
}

companion object {
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance(value: String) =
        DataFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {
                putString(DATA, value)
            }
        }
}

override fun getData(value: String) {
    Log.e("checkParam", " interface: $value")
}
```

}

Interface

```
 interface  FetchDataInterface{
    fun getData(value:String)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryout this onces

In activity.....

```
 TextEditorDialogFragment textEditorDialogFragment =
                TextEditorDialogFragment.show(this, text, colorCode);
```

In Fragment....

```
public class TextEditorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

   public static final String TAG = TextEditorDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName();
   String inputText;
   int colorCode;

   public static TextEditorDialogFragment show(@NonNull AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, @NonNull String inputText_, @ColorInt int colorCode_) {
        inputText =inputText_;
        colorCode=colorCode_;
        TextEditorDialogFragment fragment = new TextEditorDialogFragment();
        fragment.show(appCompatActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), TAG);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_text_dialog, container, false);
    }
}
```